# Русские значения в joda-time

Tags: android

Подскажите как организовать значения на русском языке "Часов""Минут".
Организован
duration.setText(duration);
Показывает 10 min, как сделать 10 мин?

Comment: Поищите в используемых классах возможность указать Locale.

Comment: https://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Custom_Formatters